# unable to extract JsonPath in dot-notation

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Given the below Json

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
    }
},
"expensive": 10
}
```

I am using the below config for extracting the json path of all author's of book

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();
Object read = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(jsonStringRaw).read("$.store.book[*].author");
```

I am getting the below output which is in bracket–notation

```
"$['store']['book'][0]['author']"
"$['store']['book'][1]['author']"
"$['store']['book'][2]['author']"
"$['store']['book'][3]['author']"
```

**However, I want output in dot–notation**

```
$.store.book[0].title
$.store.book[1].title
$.store.book[2].title
$.store.book[3].title
```

I am unable to extract JsonPath in **dot-notation**.

Comment: The output is in bracket–notation because it's valid for all scenarios. If the field names have space or special characters the dot notation doesn't work.

Comment: `title` doesn't exist in you input so you won't match anything.